# Через что лучше реализовать Стэк и очередь - массив или вектор?

Tags: очередь, стек

Реализую вручную stack и queue. Что будет эффективнее использовать для хранения элементов, массив или вектор?

Comment: Что значит эффективнее? Определите точно. Для эффективности разных операций подходят разные несущие структуры данных. И да, нет такой одной козырной структуры данных, которая была бы эффективнее всех других для реализации стека и очереди во _всех_ аспектах. Так что выкатывайте ваши критерии эффективности.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос без привязки к языку носит абстрактный характер. Сначала нужно реализовать стек, потом очередь можно сделать на 2 стеках (но не нужно). Стек можно реализовывать на чём угодно, что может безболезненно расширятся, массив расширить не получится, придётся создавать новый копировать элементы и удалять старый. По сути это же делает вектор...

Поэтому ответ - вектор, если профайлер покажет узкое место в неё то переписать на массивы и делать ручное перевыделение (не факт что будет быстрее, нужно всё делать аккуратно). Если же можно ограничить размер стека сверху неким приемлемым значением, то разницы нет. Или массив или вектор сразу растянуть.

Answer (score 1):

Статья со сравнением производительности: http://microfork.com/stdvector-stdlist-stdqueue-preformance-analisys/

При самостоятельной реализации: используйте профайлер, и тестируйте на своих реальных данных и **в своих приложениях**. Как минимум нужно учесть работу процессорного кэша (выделять память страницами, группировать часто используемые данные в смежные области памяти, делать предвыборку если есть возможность прогнозирования использования данных) и особенности работы SMP.

И зависит от размера и разброса размеров ваших данных: например если работаете с массивом данных не более N Mb (причем гарантированно меньше RAM/k), эффективнее всего будет сразу выделить максимум памяти **одним блоком** под классический сишный массив, и реализовать стек/очередь на нем (не забыв использовать выравнивание данных в памяти).